# Post method not work properly in different server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, server, guzzle

I use Laravel.
This is the code

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->post($urls['payment_generate'], [
    'form_params' => [
        'ClientID' => 'client_id',
        'Username' => 'username',
        'Password' => 'some-password',
        'Description' => 'Order description',
        'Amount' => 500,
        'OrderID' => 8349689468,
        'BackURL' => 'back url'
    ]
]);
```

I have two ubuntu server with same parameters.
One server it work fine. but other it not send post request and finally I get this error

> 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.15.6

I dumped two $clinets and here result. This one is working server

```
Client {#342 ▼
  -config: array:7 [▼
    "handler" => HandlerStack {#340 ▶}
    "allow_redirects" => array:5 [▶]
    "http_errors" => true
    "decode_content" => true
    "verify" => true
    "cookies" => false
    "headers" => array:1 [▼
      "User-Agent" => "GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.58.0 PHP/7.1.20-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1"
    ]
  ]
}
```

This one is not working server

```
Client {#270 ▼
  -config: array:7 [▼
    "handler" => HandlerStack {#322 ▶}
    "allow_redirects" => array:5 [▶]
    "http_errors" => true
    "decode_content" => true
    "verify" => true
    "cookies" => false
    "headers" => array:1 [▼
      "User-Agent" => "GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.58.0 PHP/7.1.28-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3"
    ]
  ]
}
```

All config is same only different **User-Agent** 
How I can fix ?

Comment: are  php.ini configurations same, espacially `max_execution_time`

Comment: First one get response in 1 seconds. I tried many times

Comment: Does the server that _receives_ the POST request have firewall restrictions that cause it to accept the POST from your old host but not your new one? If it is just dropping packets from your new host, you might see behavior like this.

Comment: @Davit, I think additional code snippet is needed

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski No any restriction with this request, It is public

Comment: @SomeDev this is a main part. After it `$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();`

Comment: But if I add `dd(1)`; between this codes. In second case I did not get any result. But for working server I get output 1